# Create Vcf file from ABPeoplePickerNavigationController in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I am new to IOS Swift development and I want to send .vcf file to server.And I am using ABPeoplePickerNavigationController to pick the contact., Following is the code which I am using

```
  let picker = ABPeoplePickerNavigationController()
        picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self

        if picker.respondsToSelector(Selector("predicateForEnablingPerson")) {
            picker.predicateForEnablingPerson = NSPredicate(format: "emailAddresses.@count > 0")
        }

        presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

After picking contact the delegate method is firing

```
  func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!, didSelectPerson person: ABRecordRef!) {
}
```

Now I want to get the vcf data. How can i get this, please help me...

Comment: You can learn a lot about how to get data from the address book here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/97936/address-book-tutorial-swift-ios - Then you'll have to create a VCF file with it which I'm not sure how to do.

Comment: Hi tried your link but there is no methods to create vcf file from contacts

Comment: http://gatkforums.broadinstitute.org/discussion/1268/what-is-a-vcf-and-how-should-i-interpret-it

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the answer after long research

```
func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!, didSelectPerson record: ABRecordRef!) {
      let peopleArray: CFArray = [record]
      let vCardData: NSData = ABPersonCreateVCardRepresentationWithPeople(peopleArray).takeRetainedValue()
      var ok:Bool = fileManager.createFileAtPath("filePath",contents: vCardData , attributes:nil)
}
```

Save the file as vcf file, thanks for the support from stack overflow